# navigate and print sql database

Tags: c#

I am writing an app to allow you to watch and open the tables in the db. I want to open the table by user entering a number (index of list) and print out whats inside the chosen table. I've tried:

```
   using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
        {
            List<System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaTable> tables = db.Mapping.GetTables().ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < tables.Count(); i++)
            {
                var s = tables[i].TableName;
                Console.WriteLine(i+". "+s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Choose index to open");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(str);  
}    }
```

I need a query that selects the right table based on the index.

Comment: why not use a report viewer?

Answer (score 2):

Read it using the same way (tables[index]):

```
"SELECT * from " + tables[number].TableName
```

Comment: i have try this and no good : List < System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaTable> query =
                from t in tables[number].TableName
                select tables[number];